# CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions When run tests

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, autotest

Please help. I think that there is a mistake when initializing the page

```
public class AuthStepDefinitions {

private final AuthPage authPage = new AuthPage();

@When("^user on Auth Page$")
public void onAuthPage() {
    AuthPage.getStartPage();
}
```

etc.

```
public class AuthPage extends TestBase {

private String loginPassrod = "test@test.test";

@FindBy(id = "USER_LOGIN")
private WebElement loginInput;

@FindBy(id = "USER_PASSWORD")
private WebElement userPassword;

@FindBy(className = "btn")
private WebElement btnEntrance;

@FindBy(css = "table.dataTable")
private WebElement table;

@FindBy(css = "a.button-new")
private WebElement create;

@FindBy(className = "sidebar-profile")
private WebElement profile;

public AuthPage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
}
```

etc.

```
public abstract class TestBase {

/**
 * Default timeout for waiting
 */
private static final int ELEMENT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 20;

protected static WebDriver driver;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", BaseProperties.driverDir );
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

protected static void onMainPage() {
    driver.get("хxx");
}
```

etc.

I think that there's some problem here

```
    private final AuthPage authPage = new AuthPage();
    PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
}
```

Here is some info that might help

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjlNT.png)

Here is whole stack trace

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=63014:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\IdeaProjects\TestNetGo\target\test-classes;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.13-beta-3\junit-4.13-beta-3.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-chrome-driver-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-remote-driver-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-api-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.12\byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\27.1-jre\guava-27.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\2.5.2\checker-qual-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.2.0\error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.17\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.17.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.14.0\okhttp-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.17.2\okio-1.17.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-edge-driver-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-xpi-driver\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-firefox-xpi-driver-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-firefox-driver-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-ie-driver-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-opera-driver-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-safari-driver-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\4.0.0-alpha-1\selenium-support-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\htmlelements\htmlelements-all\1.15\htmlelements-all-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\htmlelements\htmlelements-java\1.15\htmlelements-java-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\lambdaj\lambdaj\2.3.3\lambdaj-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.5\cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.5\cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-html\0.2.3\cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.0.5\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-junit\1.2.5\cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\allure\allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor\1.6.2\allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\allure\allure-java-aspects\1.5.2\allure-java-aspects-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\allure\allure-java-adaptor-api\1.5.2\allure-java-adaptor-api-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\allure\allure-java-annotations\1.5.2\allure-java-annotations-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\apache\tika\tika-core\1.7\tika-core-1.7.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.8.3\aspectjrt-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\allure\allure-commons\1.5.2\allure-commons-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\allure\allure-model\1.5.2\allure-model-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\jaxb2_commons\jaxb2-basics-runtime\0.9.3\jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.9.3.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\ru\qatools\commons\properties\2.0.RC5\properties-2.0.RC5.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\info\cukes\gherkin\2.12.2\gherkin-2.12.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging-api\1.1\commons-logging-api-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-testng\1.2.5\cucumber-testng-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.9.9\testng-6.9.9.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.48\jcommander-1.48.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.7.0\ant-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.7.0\ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.15\snakeyaml-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\beanshell\bsh\2.0b4\bsh-2.0b4.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.11\jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.11\jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.11\jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1.1\activation-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.5\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.5\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\Mark100F\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 runners.firstTestRunner

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions.AuthStepDefinitions

    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:41)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/WrapsElement
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.utils.HtmlElementUtils.isTypifiedElement(HtmlElementUtils.java:58)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.utils.HtmlElementUtils.isTypifiedElement(HtmlElementUtils.java:54)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.loader.decorator.HtmlElementDecorator.decorate(HtmlElementDecorator.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:102)
    at pages.AuthPage.<init>(AuthPage.java:33)
    at stepDefinitions.AuthStepDefinitions.<init>(AuthStepDefinitions.java:10)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 55 more


Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Failed scenarios:
authPage.feature:7 # Scenario: LogIn om Auth Page

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
4 Steps (1 failed, 3 skipped)
0m0,407s

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions.AuthStepDefinitions
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:41)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/WrapsElement
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.utils.HtmlElementUtils.isTypifiedElement(HtmlElementUtils.java:58)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.utils.HtmlElementUtils.isTypifiedElement(HtmlElementUtils.java:54)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.loader.decorator.HtmlElementDecorator.decorate(HtmlElementDecorator.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:102)
    at pages.AuthPage.<init>(AuthPage.java:33)
    at stepDefinitions.AuthStepDefinitions.<init>(AuthStepDefinitions.java:10)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 55 more


cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions.AuthStepDefinitions

    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:41)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/WrapsElement
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.utils.HtmlElementUtils.isTypifiedElement(HtmlElementUtils.java:58)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.utils.HtmlElementUtils.isTypifiedElement(HtmlElementUtils.java:54)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.loader.decorator.HtmlElementDecorator.decorate(HtmlElementDecorator.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:102)
    at pages.AuthPage.<init>(AuthPage.java:33)
    at stepDefinitions.AuthStepDefinitions.<init>(AuthStepDefinitions.java:10)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 55 more

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/Mark100F/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.5/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Please use English to write questions!

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace, instead of just an image of the first three lines of it?

Comment: Done. the question has been edited

Comment: This looks like it could be a project setup issue.  If you're using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, then cleaning and rebuilding your project might help.  If this doesn't work, you might want to re-check the Cucumber documentation to be sure that you've set everything up correctly.  Sorry that I'm unable to give more help, but someone else might be able to.

Answer (score 0):

For me helps next:

```
public AuthPage() {
        super.setup();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

dependencies in Pom.xml have been updated, and deleted unnecessary.

Still might help https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/page-object-design-pattern-with-selenium-pagefactory-in-cucumber/

Answer (score 0):

cucumber cannot initialize selenium classes during instantiation.
So I would recommend you to remove such initializations.

It solved mine as well.

You need to replace below line:
private String loginPassrod = "test@test.test";
& write it as :
private String loginPassrod;
& initialize this string inside any method as per your requirement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31470640)

Answer (score -1):

Your driver is not initialized while calling Pagefactory initElements methods. Updating the Authpage contructor as given below may resolve your issue.

```
public AuthPage() {
    super.setup();
    TestBase.onMainPage();
    PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(TestBase.driver)), this);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it really helps to open browser and open MainPage, but after that the same error

Comment: it's falling here - throw new CucumberException(String.format("Failed to instantiate %s", type), e); - when PageFactory.initElements

Comment: looks like version conflict. check selenium and cucumber version.

Comment: How should it be?

Comment: upgrade cucumber version and check

Comment: which dependencies are you using?